# Python. Multi-procressing

Tags: python, multithreading

Last attempt to get an answer.

I need to run 4 functions in an infinite loop on different threads.

The **error** is that only the first thread runs. Feel free to ask why the functions are like what they are.

```
import time
import threading
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'}

def carrigaline(): #Get the first Ad's link
    while True:

        try:
            page = requests.get(
                'https://www.daft.ie/property-for-sale/carrigaline-and-surrounds-cork?salePrice_from=200000&salePrice_to=300000',
                headers=headers).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
            divs = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': None})
            cur_carri = 'https://www.daft.ie' + divs[0].get('href')
            return cur_carri
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass

def crosshaven():
    while True:
        try:
            page = requests.get(
                'https://www.daft.ie/property-for-sale/crosshaven-cork?salePrice_from=200000&salePrice_to=300000',
                headers=headers).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
            divs = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': None})
            cur_haven = 'https://www.daft.ie' + divs[0].get('href')
            return cur_haven
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass

def minane():
    while True:
        try:
            page = requests.get(
                'https://www.daft.ie/property-for-sale/minane-bridge-cork?salePrice_from=200000&salePrice_to=300000',
                headers=headers).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
            divs = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': None})
            cur_min = 'https://www.daft.ie' + divs[0].get('href')
            return cur_min
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass
def ballygarvan():
    while True:
        try:
            page = requests.get(
                'https://www.daft.ie/property-for-sale/ballygarvan-cork?salePrice_from=200000&salePrice_to=300000',
                headers=headers).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
            divs = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': None})
            cur_bally = 'https://www.daft.ie' + divs[0].get('href')
            return cur_bally
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass



first_run = True

while True:
    print("Starting 1st thread")
    time.sleep(6) #Sleep 5 minutes
    bally = ballygarvan()
    first_run = False
    new_bally = ballygarvan()
    print(new_bally)
    if not first_run:
        if new_bally != bally:
            print("New Ad")
            continue

while True:
    print("starting second")
    time.sleep(5) #Sleep 5 minutes
    min_a = minane()
    first_run = False
    new_mina = minane()
    print(new_mina)
    if not first_run:
        if new_mina != min_a:
            print("New Ad")
            continue
while True:
    print("starting third")
    time.sleep(7) #Sleep 5 minutes
    carr = carrigaline()
    first_run = False
    new_carr = carrigaline()
    print(new_carr)
    if not first_run:
        if new_carr != carr:
            print("New Ad")
            continue

while True:
    print("starting fourth")
    time.sleep(9) #Sleep 5 minutes
    cross = crosshaven()
    first_run = False
    new_cross = crosshaven()
    print((new_cross))
    if not first_run:
        if new_cross != cross:
            print("New Ad")
            continue


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=carrigaline, name='t1')
    t1.start()
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=minane, name='t2')
    t2.start()
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=crosshaven, name='t3')
    t3.start()
    t4 = threading.Thread(target=ballygarvan, name='t4')
    t4.start()
```

Comment: You never break out of any of the `while True:` loops. So you're stuck in the first one, and never get to the code that creates threads.

Comment: The message `Starting 1st thread` isn't in the code that starts threads. It calls `ballygarvan()` without creating a thread.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with that code that runs before you create the threads, so I don't know what to put in the answer.

Comment: When I write an answer, I try to explain what's wrong and how to fix it. I know what's wrong, I don't know how to fix it because it's not clear what it's supposed to do.

Comment: The prints, I added later, to see what is happening. I am trying to run these functions on a different thread. Does that suffice?, Each function needs to go to a url to see if the div text has changed. There are 4 different urls, that is why 4 functions. They need to check continiously, for an infinite period of time..that is the problem, in a nuthsell. I cannot map these functions..you see?

Comment: But what are all the `while True:` loops for? Why aren't they in the threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you expect your code to start at

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=carrigaline, name='t1')
```

But it actually enters this while loop first :

```
first_run = True

while True:
    print("Starting 1st thread")
    time.sleep(6) #Sleep 5 minutes
    bally = ballygarvan()
    first_run = False
    new_bally = ballygarvan()
    print(new_bally)
    if not first_run:
        if new_bally != bally:
            print("New Ad")
            continue
```

and since it is an infinite loop the code is stuck there.

This happens because the loop is not inside any function.
So main function is never called and your threads are not started.